# GoogleAPIs integration with React Native / Expo

Tags: react-native, google-api, expo

I am trying to create a React Native / Expo app where I can use the YouTube Data V3 API's (video insert) but I am having difficulty understanding how to use `fetch()` in React Native to get the `access_key` by authenticating a google user through Google oauth2 consent screen.

This is my code so far:

```
fetch(
        'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?' +
        'client_id=' + clientId + '&' +
        'redirect_uri=http://localhost:19006&' +
        'response_type=token&' +
        'scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly&' +
        'include_granted_scopes=true&' +
        'state=pass-through value',

        {
          method: 'GET'
        }                
      );
```

I am getting  `from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.` and `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch` error in Chrome console. If I copy paste the link in a new tab in my browser the consent page is working.

I managed it to work using Javascript code but in React Native I can't get it to work. I am following the documentation at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#js-client-library

I searched GitHub and StackOverflow for possible solutions but I can't find any for React Native/Expo. I also tried the [Node.Js Googleapis client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) but as I understand it is not compatible with React Native/Expo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the following npm package or search for the relevant npm package like below for AppAuth react-native:

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth

Also check out the documentation or example:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/16/build-react-native-authentication-oauth-2